# Login issue , in $_SESSION[' IDONTKNOWHERE ']=$rowacc[0];

Tags: php, session, authentication

THIS code is solved but there some problem in the last code

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sqlacc="SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN accounts ON 
account.mem_id =members.mem_id WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";
$resultacc = mysql_query($sqlacc);
$countacc = mysql_num_rows($resultacc);
$rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($resultacc, MYSQL_NUM);
```

This is my problem i dont know what field name will put in $_SESSION[' '],

```
if($countacc==1){
$_SESSION[' IDONTKNOWHERE ']=$rowacc[0];
$_SESSION[' IDONTKNOWHERE ']=$rowacc[1];
header("location:content/index.php");
}
else{
header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Use PDO for mysql http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numerical keys for fetching data from the record set is a bit confusing, so I would suggest you to use associative keys instead. Firstly, print your whole record set using the following code :

```
echo 'details = <br><pre>';
print_r($rowacc);
```

This will output your record set in a well formatted manner, so that you can get an exact idea of what data have been fetched by you SQL query. You will also be able to see the numerical as well as the associative keys. So for getting the data you can use something like :

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $rowacc['firstname'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $rowacc['password'];
```

Later you can access those stored session values as :

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make any variable name as your session variable.
Same as the naming convention for variables.
Session variables are named for later accessing, so be meaningful, identifiable  and relates to its value.

Comment: but i have 2 table joined 
SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN accounts ON 
account.mem_id =members.mem_id WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'"

Comment: better check what we get from $rowacc[0] and $rowacc[1], then name the session variable according to that.

Answer (score 0):

They are key indexes. Use any value so that later on you can access them. For example if you are storing username in session then that will be $_SESSION['username']. I suggest you to use print_r($rowacc); So that you know what value stored in your record set.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it should be:

```
$_SESSION['mem_id']=$rowacc[0];
$_SESSION['mem_firstname']=$rowacc[1];
```

If you can share the script where the login is being checked, we can provide a better solution.